# css search form not working

Tags: css, forms, search, button

so I upgraded my site into responsive template, all done but stuck here!
so I know this is something very simple as a b c , but for the life of me cannot fig it out :*(
    http://www.example.com/cards/holiday-greeting-cards.php
here on top right the search button with magnifying glass icon... how to make it work!
the other search button which says "search holiday cards"(which will be removed once this one starts working) is working fine...
can anyone please please help please
thanks in adv

Comment: well, the other search field is working because it's inside a FORM element with appropriately defined action and method attributes, along with a submit button. 
The input field that is not working is just an input field, you need to wrap it inside a form tag, similar to the 'Holiday greeting cards' field

Comment: ok yes so putting form inside the div worked, thank you salvenko and all but it is working with "enter" key how do I make it so that clicking on magnifying glass icon works?

Comment: You ned to have a submit button inside a form if you want to submit a form with a mouse click. Currently that magnifying glass is just a background image for the input field. You can use the solution in answer provided by divix below and add an invisible button over the magnifying glass.

Comment: wow yeah!!! that worked so AWESOMELY!!!!!!!1 just what I wanted!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

This **isn't** perfect solution and it's a more of a hack, but it's really short and does its job.

Append this just after: `<input type="text" placeholder="Search">`

```
<input type="submit" style="
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    opacity: 0;
">
```

Comment: ok yes so putting form inside the div worked, thank you salvenko and all but it is working with "enter" key how do I make it so that clicking on magnifying glass icon works?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a class to your input box (you can also do an input find in search_box)

```
<div class="search_box pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search_input" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

You can use jQuery to get the content (this example only reacts to the enter key)

```
$('.search_input')
    .keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) { // if you press enter
            window.location.assign('/cards/search-results-xmas.php?keywords=' + $('.search_input').val());
        }
    });
```